# joomla template override search plugin

Tags: php, joomla, search-engine, joomla3.4, k2

I am using the Joomla 3. 
I would like to know how can I override the Joomla search plugin under template.

I tried copying these files

```
/plugins/search/k2/k2.php
/plugins/search/k2/k2.xml
```

under the `/templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME/html` to create plg_search_k2 folder. It doesn't work. Anyone know how can we override the search plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Template Manager** for create your overrides, first see the step bu step here:

- How to use the Template Manager
  https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager

Now create your override in the Column **Modules** > **mod_k2_tools**
Find the file in:
  `/templates/your_template/html/mod_k2_tools/search.php`

Find another example specifically for plugins here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: I am using the Joomla search, not the K2 tool search. You suggested answer is to override the module k2 tools. I just want to edit these two files
/plugins/search/k2/k2.php
/plugins/search/k2/k2.xml

Comment: In the name of your files you mention k2, find an example for plugins in the last link for this block "Plugin Override example"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that example before, but it seems do not work on the search plugin. I just wonder is there any other alternative.